# How do I create a relationship from a nodeA to another specific child node related to the nodeA in a tree using cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

'Alice'-[WORKS_FOR]->'Twitter'

'Tax2022'-[PROJECT_OF]->'Twitter'

I want to create a [HAS_READ_ACCESS] relation between 'Alice' that [WORKS_FOR] 'Twitter' and the 'Tax2022' [PROJECT_OF] 'Twitter'

Tried but did not work.

```
MATCH (u:User), (t:Tenant), (p:Project)
WHERE u.name = 'Alice' AND t.name = 'Twitter' AND p.Name = 'TAX2022'
MERGE (u)-[r:HAS_READ_ACCESS]->(p)
```

Kindly Advice

Comment: What didn't work. Do you use users of projects with duplicated names?

Comment: The output is "(no changes, no records)" and I do not see the relationship getting created. The Users are unique

Comment: This worked: `MATCH (p:Project{name:"AP2022"})-[r:PROJECT_OF]->(t:Tenant{name:"Twitter"})<-[w:WORKS_FOR]-(u) 
WHERE u.name='Alice'
MERGE (u)-[a:HAS_READ_ACCESS]->(p)`